# Is the sum of a series of continuous functions $f_n$ defined by $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t)$ neccesarily continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is the sum of a series of continuous functions $f_n$ defined by $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(t)$ neccesarily continuous ?

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be continuous.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $x_0 \in X$.

For $\forall \ n \in \mathbb N \ \exists \delta >0: d(x_0,x) \le \delta \Rightarrow |f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)| \le\epsilon$.

If the series was finite, say $K$ terms, I could choose $\epsilon^{'} = \epsilon / K$ and $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, ..., \delta_K$}, where $\delta_j$ satisfy $d(x_0,x) \le \delta \Rightarrow |f_j(x_0)-f_j(x)| \le\epsilon^{'}$ for $1 \le j \le K$.

However the series is infinite, so I cannot choose such an $\epsilon^{'} > 0$.

Any suggestions on how to prove/disprove the claim ?

Comment: You may not always sum continuous function to get a limiting function. For e.g $f_{(2n+1)} \equiv 1$, $f_{(2n)} \equiv -1$

Comment: As DiffeoR said, you should really add the assumption that the sum actually converges pointwise.

Comment: The question does not assume this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true without an assumption on the speed of the convergence.

Consider $X = [0,1]$, $f_n(x) = x^{n-1}-x^n, n\ge 1$.
The sum is $$
f(x)  = \lim_{N\to \infty} 1-x^N=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x <1\\
0 & \text{if } x =1\end{cases}
$$

[image]

---

If you assume that the convergence is uniform:
$$
\forall r>0\ \ \exists N>0 \ \ 
N'\ge N\implies\forall x\in X\ \  
d\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N'} f_n(x) - f(x)
\right)<r
$$
then this becomes true: let $\epsilon >0$, take $r =\epsilon/3$.

As $\sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(x) $ is continuous, there is $\delta_r$ such as
$$
d(x,y)\le \delta_r\implies
d\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(x) , \sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(y)
\right)\le r;
\\
d\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(x) , f(x)
\right)<r;\ \ \ 
d\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(y), f(y)
\right)<r;\\
\implies 
d\left( f(y) ,f(x)
\right)\le
d\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(x) , f(x)
\right)+
d\left( \sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(y), f(y)
\right)+d\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N_r} f_n(x) , \sum_{n=1}^{N} f_n(y)
\right)\\ \le 3r = \epsilon.
$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by speed of convergence ? Since $0 \le x < 1$ we have $x^N \rightarrow 0$ for $N \rightarrow \infty$. I really like this counter-example. It proves the sum is discountinuous for $x = 1$ right ?

Comment: You need the uniform convergence of the series.

Comment: Is the point of this illustration that for $N \rightarrow \infty$ it may converge so slowly that ... But still $x = 1$ implies $f(x)=0$ and $x < 1$ implies $f(x) = 1$ ?

Comment: It converges slowly around 1. Even for $N$ big, you remain close to 0 (thanks to continuity) because the points close to 1 have a slow convergence.

Comment: I added the proof in the case of uniform convergence.

Comment: In your counter-example without the assumption of uniform convergence does it fail ? In the question, I don't assume uniform convergence, so I assume I should find a counter-example and yours suffice ? I'm a little confused now, since I'm new to the subject of series of functions.

Comment: 1) with uniform convergence you keep continuity; 2) in my counterexample you don't keep continuity; hence there is no uniform convergence

Comment: Just a suggestion: Since you talk about speed of convergence, it would be helpful to include a plot of $f_n(x)=x^{n-1}-x^n$ for some $n$'s, that'll show that they don't converge uniformly.

Comment: is it relevant? this is the sequence of partial sums that do not converge uniformly...